# Importing/Exporting prototypes in ES6

Tags: javascript, webpack, phaser-framework, es6-modules

Context: 
I am currently working on a game with the Phaser framework. I was given a code base to work with, so it cannot be changed. Phaser no native way to import/export, so I use webpack and babel to get around [with lots of help from this template.](https://github.com/lean/phaser-es6-webpack)

My issue stems from trying to import and export the following code:

Given code:

```
AchievementManager = function(a) { 
    this.game = a, 
    this._playerDataModified = !1, 
    this.newLevels = [], 
};


AchievementManager.prototype = { 
    _getTotalLoyaltyPoints: function() { 
        return 1;
    }
}
```

My attempt to export. Returns compile error(not in browser) 'Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected {' in reference to AchievementManager:

```
export AchievementManager = function(a) { 
    this.game = a, 
    this._playerDataModified = !1, 
    this.newLevels = [], 
};


export AchievementManager.prototype = { 
    _getTotalLoyaltyPoints: function() { 
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me find out how to export/import classes that are written in this form, while maintaining core concepts like prototyping functions, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting the constructor function is enough. The prototype is a property of it, you can access it just like that (if you ever needed it - the usual way to interact with imported constructors is to `new` them). You don't have to put some kind of "visibility annotation" on the property assignment. Your current code does not work because one can only export variable bindings in ES6.

You should write

```
export function AchievementManager(a) { 
    this.game = a;
    this._playerDataModified = false;
    this.newLevels = [];
}

AchievementManager.prototype._getTotalLoyaltyPoints = function() { 
    return 1;
};
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Works through `new` and property notation, just as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You already export `AchievementManager`. There isn't any good reason to export `AchievementManager.prototype`. Just use `.prototype` on AchievementManager when you import it.

Anyway, if you want to:

```
AchievementManager.prototype = { 
    _getTotalLoyaltyPoints: function() { 
        return 1;
    }
}
export const AchievementManagerPrototype = AchievementManager.prototype;
```